# Sort of carousel for text?

Tags: android

How is it possible to create this kind of **text carousel** in Android?

[image]

Is there a widget with the same aspect with chevron or something? 
I am looking to implement similar utility than this picture. The user will see always the current date as tab selected by default and can choose the day before or after depending on their needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    ...
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  }
}
```

Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.OpenCraft:AnimatedTextCarousel:-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Start your own animated text carousel with:

```
 yourAnimatedTextCarouselViewPager.setItems(getYourStringArray());
```

Specify the animated text carousel component inside your layout file:

```
  <com.gcherubini.animatedtextcarousel.AnimatedTextCarouselViewPager
            android:id="@+id/animatedTextCarousel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

If you would like to know what is the new selected text, when you are setting your viewpager items just pass the interface as below:

```
  yourAnimatedTextCarouselViewPager.setItemsWithListener(getYourStringArray(), new AnimatedTextCarouselListener() {
            @Override public void onTextSelected(String selectedText) { }
  });
```